# Emulate a keyboard button via the Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, numlock

My keyboard doesn't have a <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key, and none of the registry edits work for some reason.

Can I use the Command Prompt or PowerShell on Windows 10 to "press" a key? I'm looking for something like `press pgup` to press the <kbd>Page Up</kbd> Key in the Command Prompt or PowerShell, but for <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### How do I toggle numlock status using PowerShell.

Use the following script:

> ```
> $wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
> $wsh.SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}')
> ```

Source StackOverflow answer [PowerShell: Toggle “Num Lock” on and off.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795442/3536342) by [Andy Arismendi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251123/andy-arismendi)

As pointed out by [ABashore](https://superuser.com/users/149902/abashore) in his comment this can be shortened as follows:

```
$wshell.SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}')
```

Comment: It doesnt appear that you need to define "wsh" to do what he needs. I was able to simply toggle the NUMLOCK with just a single line.

Comment: @ABashore Cool. I've upvoted your answer

Comment: For one line command what worked to me was:     (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}')

Answer (score 10):

Here's a powershell line that will toggle your NUMLOCK. I've tested this and it works on my Logitech K120 USB keyboard.

```
$wshell.SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}')
```

[Here's a list of the other SendKey codes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943(v=office.10).aspx)

If you need to send the keystroke to an interactive application, more code will be needed.

Comment: Did you mean I don't need to define `$wshell`? Is it like a keyword? If I do `if(-not [console]::NumberLock){ $wshell.SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}'); }` in my .ps1 file, it complains `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Answer (score 0):

Batch

Without creating temporary files.
The 'loop' was shown only so that you could open a notebook for output. Remove it after.

```
    @echo off
        :loop
            ::------------begin main code------------
            set command=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell').SendKeys('WoW{ENTER}{ENTER}');
            for /f "delims=" %%i in ('mshta "javascript:%command%close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'));"') do set
            ::-------------end main code-------------
            timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
        goto :loop
```

Comment: would you mind updating your answer to give a little more information as to what’s going on in that script?